# Extracting table of holdings from (Edgar 13-F filings) TXT (pre-2013) with python

Tags: parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests, edgar

I am working on extracting a table of holdings from 13-F form on EDGAR. Before 2013 holdings were given in a txt file (see [example](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1067983/000119312512470800/d434976d13fhr.txt)).
The output I am aiming for is a pd.DataFrame with same shape as the "Form 13F Information Table" in txt file (10 columns and each line in a separate row).

I have tried to use BeautifulSoup, which turned table into a tag object, but I can't figure out how to format this to go into the dataframe as described above.

This is my code attempt:

```
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(filing_url_13f).content, 'lxml')
holdings = soup2.find_all('table')

#This is my attempt to turn the content into a list:
lixt=[]
for x in soup2.find_all(['c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c','c']  ):
    for line in x:
        lixt.append(line)
x=lixt[1]
l=[]
for string in x.strings:
    l.append(repr(string))
el=l[7]
```

And this is where I get stuck as *el* returns the below. I can't split it by \n, as there are often \n within company name (AMERICAN\n  EXPRESS CO).

> \nAMERICAN\n  EXPRESS CO        COM           025816109      112,209     1,952,142 Shared-Defined 4           1,952,142       -        -\nAMERICAN\n  EXPRESS CO        COM           025816109      990,116    17,225,400 Shared-Defined 4, 5       17,225,400       -        -\nAMERICAN\n  EXPRESS CO        COM           025816109       48,274       839,832 Shared-Defined 4, 7          839,832       -        -\nAMERICAN\n  EXPRESS CO        COM           025816109      111,689     1,943,100 Shared-Defined 4, 8, 11    1,943,100       -        -\nAMERICAN\n  EXPRESS CO        COM           025816109      459,532     7,994,634 Shared-Defined 4, 10       7,994,634       -        -\nAMERICAN\n  EXPRESS CO        COM           025816109    6,912,308   120,255,879 Shared-Defined 4, 11     120,255,879       -        -\nAMERICAN\n  EXPRESS CO        COM           025816109       80,456     1,399,713 Shared-Defined 4, 13       1,399,713       -        -\nARCHER DANIELS\n  MIDLAND CO        COM           039483102      163,151     5,956,600 Shared-Defined 4, 5        5,956,600       -        -\nBANK OF NEW\n  YORK MELLON\n  CORP              COM           064058100      206,661     8,041,300 Shared-Defined 4           8,041,300       -        -\nBANK OF NEW\n  YORK MELLON\n  CORP              COM           064058100       46,104     1,793,915 Shared-Defined 2, 4, 11    1,793,915       -        -\nBANK OF NEW\n  YORK MELLON\n  CORP              COM           064058100      251,827     9,798,700 Shared-Defined 4, 8, 11    9,798,700       -        -\nCOCA COLA CO        COM           191216100       29,000       800,000 Shared-Defined 4             800,000       -        -\n

I will be very grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, these old EDGAR filings are terrible (not that the new ones are much better). This one is particularly bad, since longer entry lines were split into separate lines in order to get them to fit the page.

So the following should get you close enough to what you want:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

req = requests.get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1067983/000119312512470800/d434976d13fhr.txt')

#next is a helper function to put back those longer entires
def lst_bunch(l,lenth=4):
    i=0
    while i < len(l):
        if len(l[i])<lenth:
            l[i] += l.pop(i+1)
        i += 1
    for item in l:
        if len(item)<lenth:
            lst_bunch(l,lenth)
    else:
        return l

tabs = req.text.replace('<TABLE>','xxx<TABLE>').split('xxx')
for tab in tabs[2:]:
    soup = bs(tab,'lxml')
    table = soup.select_one('table')
    lines = table.text.splitlines()
    lst_bunch(lines,30)
    for line in lines:
        print(line.strip())

Output:
Name of Issuer  Class  CUSIP     (In Thousands)   Amount      Discretion   Managers     Sole      Shared  None
AMERICAN  EXPRESS CO    COM    025816109      110,999     1,952,142 Shared-Defined 4           1,952,142       -   -
AMERICAN  EXPRESS CO    COM    025816109      979,436    17,225,400 Shared-Defined 4, 5       17,225,400       -   -
```

etc.

Comment: Jack, thank you, it really helps! I saw your helpful suggestions in other queries related to handling financial data. Would you be able to have a look at my other question when you have some time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64958844/adding-a-weight-constraint-to-max-sharpe-ratio-function-in-python